# MPI and GADM Boundaries

Tags: geospatial

I am looking to merge data from Oxford's Multidimensional Poverty Index (MPI) at a subnational level with GADM boundaries, but I'm finding only about 60% match rates.

Does anyone know either the location of shapefiles corresponding to MPI subnational data or how the subnational location names in MPI were selected?